# R - Loop API Call

Tags: r, api, loops

I'm using R to successful make API calls. For each individual call I need to alter one or two distinguishing ID's (in the case of the code below **activity_id** and/or **name_id**). The code is working fine however I am now in a position where I like to automate this process as opposed to manually changing the ID's for each call. I am wondering if there's a way to loop this using a data frame or list to store the relevant ID's.

I've searched across Stack however I'm yet to find or execute an appropriate solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

JPC

```
apiKey <-"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI"
example<- GET("url?activity_id=b5cb9359-f0e5-4939-9be3-fc95f8bc7d6b&name_id=f1e17fa6-c40c-4810-9c43-60939e2a9a99",add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", apiKey)))
example <-content(example,"text")
example <-fromJSON(example,flatten = TRUE)
example <-unnest(example,data)
write.csv(example,"example.csv",row.names=F)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could write a function where we dynamically generate url using `sprintf` based on `activity_id` and `name_id` passed.

```
get_data <- function(activity_id, name_id) {

   url <- sprintf('url?activity_id=%s&name_id=%s', activity_id, name_id)
   example<- httr::GET(url,add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", apiKey)))
   example <- httr::content(example,"text")
   example <- jsonlite::fromJSON(example,flatten = TRUE)
   example <- tidyr::unnest(example,data)
   return(example)
}
```

and then call it using `Map`.

```
out <- Map(get_data, activity_vec, name_vec)
```

Here `activity_vec` and `name_vec` are the vector of respective id's. This will return a list of dataframes in `out` which can be combined into one dataframe if needed before writing to csv.

---

If only `name_id` is changing we can do

```
get_data <- function(name_id) {
    url <- sprintf('url?activity_id=b5cb9359-f0e5-4939-9be3-fc95f8bc7d6&name_id=%s', name_id)
    example<- httr::GET(url,add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", apiKey)))
    example <- httr::content(example,"text")
    example <- jsonlite::fromJSON(example,flatten = TRUE)
    example <- tidyr::unnest(example,data)
    return(example)
  }

out <- lapply(name_vec, get_data)
```

Comment: Hi Ronak - Thanks for your thoughts on this post. It doesn't seem to have solved the problem. Perhaps if the activitiy_id was a constant value and only the name_id was changing this would simplify things? Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: @JPC See the update if only name_id is changing where `name_vec` is vector of name id's that you want to use.

Comment: Thank you Ronak - I appreciate the quick reply. Will let you know how I get on with this.

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah. I've played around with this over the last couple of days but no luck. The following error is consistent " Error in UseMethod("unnest") : no applicable method for 'unnest' applied to an object of class "list".

Comment: Then you need to provide a valid URL on which I can test my solution making this post reproducible. `url?activity_id=b5cb9359-f0e5-4939-9be3-fc95f8bc7d6&name_id` is not a valid URL so I don't know what type of data is returned from it.

Comment: Thanks Ronak - is there a way to share the url privately through this platform? For privacy reasons I cannot shared publicly.